# How to setup Heroku custom domain with DNS?

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, subdomain

Short story: I build a web app, hosted it on Heroku, I have a domain from a Dutch provider "mijndomein.nl" Now I want to use the custom domain for my app.

I have followed the Heroku guide, but without success, I have watched a few videos, but the DNS settings in the videos are not exactly the same as I have at the mijndomein DNS control panel, and since I don't have a lot of experience setting up DNS and domain pointing I can't figure it out for my self. I will provide a screenshot of the mijndomein settings, and probably you will laugh that I haven't figured it out already and tell me how it works.

I'm confused with the * wildcard domain, and if the www (is a subdomain or not) that's not 100% clear in the Heroku guide. Heroku says that wildcard domains are not allowed when using ACM (automatic SSL certificate), but I need to obtain SSL ofc. and mijndomein's base settings looks to be using a * wildcard DNS. How do I set it up correctly so that when I enter:

**oppascentrale.nl** -> I go to my heroku app with SSL

**www.oppascentrale.nl** -> I go to my heroku app with SSL

Do I add with or without 'www' in the heroku control panel when adding custom domain?

This is how mijndomein DNS settings looks like when I do a factory reset
[image]

I'm also not sure if I can delete some of the DNS settings lines? I can't read anywhere if any of these different settings will interfere with each other.

As you can see in the shot below, Heroku is not exactly clear about how the custom domain should be added, first with, and then without 'www.' - I have tried both, but neither seemed to work with their SSL.
[image]

I also never managed to access my app from oppascentrale.nl, Do I some how have to redirect to www.oppascentrale when hitting oppascentrale.nl? And if yes, how do i set up that?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#dns_setup ? It seems quite comprehensive. For `www` on your DNS hoster panel set a CNAME for it to `www.oppascentral.nl.herokudns.com`. For the root domain it is more complicated as only possible with some providers, see list in doc. Ask your provider if it has "ANAME" or "ALIAS" DNS records.

Comment: From the list in your screenshot only the `A` and `AAAA` records with no subdomain and the `*` CNAME wildcard are relevant to your application and Heroku, all the rest concerns other stuff.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I don't think the provider has "ANAME" or "ALIAS". will that mean that I can never redirect the root domain to www. ?

Comment: Based on Heroku documentation, it seems that you need it indeed: "Since Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, it’s necessary to use a CNAME-like record (often referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records) so that you can point your root domain to another domain. See examples below."

Comment: You are probably not the only one at your DNS hoster trying to use it for Heroku application, so try contacting them they may/should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and direct answers! Their documentation is in Dutch, so I think indeed I'm going to contact them for further help. (The organisation I build the system for is Dutch, why they chose a dutch domain provider with absolutely no English documentation) "slap"